# A word or phrase that someone says frequently is called what?

Tags: single-word-requests

A word or phrase that someone says frequently is called what? As an example, a friend says the phrase "Faithful God" frequently, say 15 times in day. So, what English word defines the term "Faithful God" with respect to the friend?

Comment: See also [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429004/name-for-a-word-that-someone-is-known-for-saying/429005#429005)

Comment: I would say "annoying".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [name for a word that someone is known for saying?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429004/name-for-a-word-that-someone-is-known-for-saying)

Answer (score 1):

If it's something distinctively his, to the point where bringing it up in conversation with Friend #2 causes him to laugh and say, "Friend #1, amiright?" it's a [**catchphrase**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_catchphrases).

> A catchphrase (alternatively spelled catch phrase) is a phrase or expression recognized by its repeated utterance.

The *OED* says it originated [from the use of "catch"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/28818) to describe things that catch the eye or ear. '**[Catchword](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/catchword#English)**' was the original way to express the idea, but is less common now.

A similar idea is the [**signature phrase**](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-signature-phrase). It's less condescending and simply expresses the idea that that idiomatic expression is strongly associated with that person. If you're expressing how fond the friend is of his own turn of phrase, you might use [**pet phrase**](https://www.thoughtco.com/pet-phrase-1691501).

Answer (score 0):

**old saw**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Old+saw)  idiom

> An oft-repeated saying, maxim, or proverb; a cliché or hackneyed
>   expression.

As in:

> My dad has a few *old saws* he never hesitates to share with my kids
>   whenever we come to visit.